# Computing average tile size (grid)

Tags: computational-geometry, graphics

I am trying to compute the average cell size on the following set of points, as seen on the picture: [image: grid]. The picture was generated using gnuplot:

```
gnuplot> plot "debug.dat" using 1:2
```

The points are almost aligned on a rectangular grid, but not quite. There is a limited bias (jitter?) of 10-15% along either X or Y (never more). How would one compute efficiently a proper partition of tiles so that there is *virtually* only one point per tile, size would be expressed as **(tilex, tiley)**. I use the word *virtually* since the 10-15% bias may have moved a point in another adjacent tile.

Just for reference, I have manually sorted (hopefully correct) and extracted the first 10 points:

```
 -133920,33480
 -132480,33476
 -131044,33472
 -129602,33467
 -128162,33463
 -139679,34576
 -138239,34572
 -136799,34568
 -135359,34564
 -133925,34562
```

Just for clarification, a valid tile as per the above description would be (1435,1060), but I am really looking for a quick automated way. A tile in my case is rectangular.

A brute force approach would be to use a Delaunay triangulation but that feels way too complex because of the restrictions of my issue (limited bias, rectangular tiles...)